# Unless I clone, I cannot get origin/master

Tags: git

Using `git version 2.11.0`.

In a cloned repository:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://path/to/repo
  Push  URL: ssh://path/to/repo
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

In the repository that initially pushed to the bare git repo using the follwoing command to set its url:

`git remote set-url origin ssh://path/to/repo`

I get:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://path/to/repo
  Push  URL: ssh://path/to/repo
  HEAD branch: master

  <Remote branch missing from here>

  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

In the repo under question:

When I `git fetch`, I **always** get the message:

```
From ssh://path/to/repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Git remote seems OK:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://path/to/repo (fetch)
origin  ssh://path/to/repo (push)
```

Git push seems OK:

```
$ git push -u
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

But `--set-upstream-to` fails:

```
$ git branch master --set-upstream-to origin/master
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/master' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

Comment: have you tried to remove remote and add it back again, `git remote remove origin`, `git remote add origin <url>`, `git fetch origin`

Comment: @shams.kool Thank you for the tip, it was the fetch setting in my gitconfig, afterall!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine the configuration files (`.git/config`) for the good clone vs the not-quite-so-good original, you will see that one of them—the good one—has an entry that reads, more or less:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The not-so-good one is missing this `fetch =` setting.

The lack of the `fetch = ...` setting is why `git fetch` in the not-so-good repository never creates `origin/master`.  It calls up the Git over at `origin`, sees that the other Git has a `master`, and brings over any commits they have that you don't ... and then *doesn't* create `origin/master` because it has nothing telling it to do that.  You wind up seeing:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

---

By contrast, in the good repository, running `git fetch` calls up the Git at `origin`, sees that the other Git has a `master`, brings over any commits they have that you don't ... and then *does* create or update `origin/master` according to the `fetch =` setting.

Running `git clone` creates the fetch setting.  Running `git remote add origin url` would create it—so [shams.kool's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682201/unless-i-clone-i-cannot-get-origin-master#comment99930353_56682201) suggesting removing and then re-creating `origin` would work—but running `git remote set-url origin url` does not create the fetch setting.

Or you can just instruct your Git to create that setting:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

in bash, for instance (or edit the config file directly in a suitable editor).